# unable to add image to imageview from camera capture

Tags: android

I am developing one application in which I have to capture image from camera and add to `ImageView`. Here I have a problem while showing image on `ImageView`. If I click save button the image is not showing on `ImageView` for the first time,but for second time it is showing,please solve my problem, I am unable to find solution for this.

**Code Snippet:**

```
        fromCamera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            /*  Log.e("OPEN", "CAMERA");

                 Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                 File f = new File(android.os.Environment
                          .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                 intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                 startActivityForResult(intent, RESUL_CameraT_LOAD_IMAGE);*/
                Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator +    
             "fav.jpg");
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
                startActivityForResult(intent, RESUL_CameraT_LOAD_IMAGE);
                uploadalertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });


    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Uri selectedImage = null;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    try {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case RESUL_CameraT_LOAD_IMAGE:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // imageView.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
                Log.e("GET IMAGE", "PATH");
                try{
                   File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator 
               + "fav.jpg");
                    bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), 300, 300);
                    uloadImgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90,
                            byteArray);

                    byte[] byte_arr = byteArray.toByteArray();
                    base64 = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, Base64.DEFAULT);
                } 
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
         }





public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) 
{ // BEST QUALITY MATCH

    //First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize, Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight) 
    {
        inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
    }
    int expectedWidth = width / inSampleSize;

    if (expectedWidth > reqWidth) 
    {
        //if(Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth) > inSampleSize) // If bigger SampSize..
        inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
    }

    options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all add the following permission in you app's manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Then check the following code which I used in my application to set s user's profile pic.

// on click listener for the camera trigger
    image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraintent = new Intent(
                    MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraintent, 101);

        }
    });
```

//onActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Uri selectedImage = null;
    Bitmap bitmap;

    try {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case 101:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (null != data) {
                    selectedImage = data.getData(); // the uri of the image
                                                    // taken
                    bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(this,
                            selectedImage, 100, 100);
                    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

//Bitmap sampling

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(Activity callingActivity,
        Uri uri, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    try {
        InputStream input = callingActivity.getContentResolver()
                .openInputStream(uri);
        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        options.inSampleSize = 2; // make the bitmap size half of the
                                    // original one
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
                reqHeight);
        input.close();

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        input = callingActivity.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, options);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {// TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
```

//calculate sample size

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and
        // keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```